# Should I put on my CV a postdoc which I am going to quit?

Tags: cv

I am currently doing a postdoc but I am looking for something else as the position turned out to be completely different with respect to the job description.

I have been in this postdoc for 4 months and I will leave as soon as I find another job. Should I include this short period on my CV?

I am applying to research positions both in academia and industry.

Comment: It is impossible to give you good feedback here. "Military related" can mean a lot of things. There would also be the issue of explaining employment gaps. If you are ashamed of your current work there are more issues.

Comment: 'Too low a workload' as a postdoc just means you get to do more work on your ideas...

Comment: *it’s not so easy* --- There's always something new to learn that one previously didn't have the time for, or polishing up or continuing something that you'd previously worked on that you had to stop for some reason, or something. Unless, I guess, you're constantly under the gaze of others or you have to account for all your hours at work. That said, I think any kind of postdoc looks better than none -- it's evidence that you achieved something, even if just getting the position. That's more than [working at a call center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/158812/49593), for example.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sufficiently clear. (There were several things I wanted to mention, such as dealing with free time, and I think I managed to have 0 characters left.) My intention at the end was that the posdoc should be included on your resume, because I don't see how it could be viewed as worse than nothing. As for whether you stay with it, that's another matter which I have nothing much to say because that involves many specific issues I don't know about (or have enough background knowledge to judge, even if I were provided more specifics) and also many issues specifically personal to you.

Comment: It would be unethical *not* to list a position you had on your academic CV.

Answer (score 4):

You absolutely should put this postdoc on your resume. It is where you are currently working, and given the times you have no good idea just how much longer you will be working there. The fact that you have a position is a positive indicator.

Now, this will raise some questions in the hiring process at other institutions, but a 4+ month hiatus would be similarly questioned. And you have good explanations as to why you want to move on. Note that in 6 or so months nobody is really going to be worried about it, since postdocs are limited term in the first place.

As an aside, I would say that you should perform more due diligence in selecting your next position, since there seems to have been some miscommunication. And, no, having a postdoc at a national lab is not generally seen as a negative either in industry or academia.